# jQuery RS Carousel - Rename the rs-carousel div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, carousel

How to rename the rs-carousel div to my_carousel (for example..)?

http://richardscarrott.github.io/jquery-ui-carousel/

Thank you very much.

Comment: Just curious as to the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Simple having a containing div with that id or class.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace it with something like:

```
$("#rs-carousel").attr("id","my_carousel");
```

However, this will probably destroy the carousel, so you will have to deal with that.